# Get all liked pages sorted by general likes

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get **Pages** liked by the user ordered descending by amount of likes each Page has...
It's difficult to get this using `Graph API` cause I'd have to fetch request like this:

```
let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/likes" parameters: nil)
```

and recursively call this inside because this request will paginate response. After I get everything I'll have to sort it locally and that's how I'd get it 
IMHO, it's a lil bit *overkill* so I've looked into a method of achieving same thing but using `FQL` and this is the query:

```
SELECT name, fan_count FROM page WHERE  page_id IN (SELECT page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid = me())  ORDER BY fan_count DESC
```

At first I was happy with this but after some test my friend told me that he can't see Messi on his list. **So I wonder what's the reason that not all Pages are show in this `FQL` query result?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t have to make separate requests for this.

The Graph API has a feature called “field expansion”, that allows you to specify that you want data from multiple “levels” in one go. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#fieldexpansion

So requesting

```
/me/likes?fields=id,name,likes
```

will give you the id, name and number of likes for each of the user’s liked pages.

(You will still have to follow the pagination links, gather all results and do the sorting on your end afterwards, since the API doesn’t currently allow for sorting.)

Answer (score 0):

FQL is deprecated and only works with older Apps using v2.0 of the Graph API. As of now, the only way to do this is to recursively get all Pages and do the sorting on your own.

Comment: why the downvote? please comment so i can improve my question if there is anything wrong.